# Hijacking links with JQuery, new links not bound

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to modernise a 50 page website which doesn't use ajax and so is really hard to maintain since every edit has to be done on 50 pages.

Now I've rid all 50 pages of duplicate HTML but it's not working well:

```
function hijax() {
  $("a").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var url = this.href;
    if (url.indexOf("index.html") != -1) {
      $('#ajax').load("home.html", function () {
        hijax();
      });
    }
    else {
      $('#ajax').load(url, function () {
        hijax();
      });
    }
  });
}
```

This works OK for the main page, but the links loaded via Ajax aren't hijacked. It seems the callback is done before the HTML is loaded.
Any way to fix that?

EDIT:

In response to Bergi:

```
$('#ajax').load("home.html", function (e) {
        hijax();
      });
```

Passing `event` in the callback causes the original code to work as expected. Joe's solution looks more elegant though, so I stick with that. Thanks guys.

Comment: If edits have to be done to multiple pages for one change, then that's not a problem to solve with ajax anyway.

Comment: Did you intend for this to be recursive?

Comment: @AlexMorrise Yes, otherwise the inline links will open a full screen page with no menu.

Comment: Replace `$("a").click(function (e) {` with `$(document).on('click', 'a', function (e) {` and remove `function hijax() {` and the last `}`. Then remove both references to `hijax();` in the ajax callbacks. This uses [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) and means the event is triggered on all current and future `a` elements.

Comment: How do you know the links are not hijacked? Try to put some logging in your functions, e.g. report the number of links which you have installed listeners every time.

Comment: @Joe Like a charm! Can you post it as answer?

Comment: @Bergi It was clear from the debugger.

Comment: @Jonathan: Well, [the docs state](http://api.jquery.com/load/) that "*the `complete` callback is executed after post-processing and HTML insertion has been performed*". Can you show us your debuggin results? Have you tried different jQuery versions?

Comment: @Bergi I've debugged it a bit more and found the answer, see edit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace:

```
$("a").click(function (e) {
```

with:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a', function (e) {
```

and remove `function hijax() {` and the last `}`.

Then remove both references to `hijax();` in the ajax callbacks.

This uses [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) and means the event is triggered on all current and future `a` elements. Your original code wasn't binding a `click` event to the newly added links.

Comment: To expand on this: the first call binds an event handler to every `a` element when it's called, so future elements aren't bound.  The latter call binds an event handler to the document that only responds to events on `a` elements, so new elements will still bubble up their events to the existing handler.

Comment: The original script *is* binding event to the newly added links by re-executing the `hijax` function after ajax content was loaded. Didn't you notice that?

Comment: @Bergi - yes, I did notice that. However, the OP said this solution worked for them so it _must_ have been they way they were binding the events.

Comment: @Bergi The callback was executed but the main-area was blank when it hit the break-point. That's why I suspect the call-back was executed too soon...